# Creating a sql file using python

Tags: python, pandas

So i have a dataset looks like:

| Col A | Col B | Col C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Nanana | Teacher | 123456 |
| Popopo | Student | 232322 |
| Cecece | Teacher | 455433 |
| Lalala | Student | 231231 |
| Poasls | Teacher | 235433 |
| Lilili | Teacher | 723543 |

I wanted to create a .sql file that contains

`SELECT function({1},{2},{3})`

then, i wanted to divide it into 2 statement each file

the expected output will be

FUNCTION_1.sql

> SELECT function(Nanana ,Teacher, 123456);

> SELECT function(Popopo,Student,232322);

FUNCTION_2.sql

> SELECT function(Cecece,Teacher, 455433);

> SELECT function(Lalala,Student,231231);

my existing code looks like:

```
file_name = function_{}.sql
iterate=df[df.columns[0]].count() / 2
query = "SELECT function({0},{1},{2})"

for x in range(int(iterate)):
    with open(file_name.format(x+1),'w') as f:
    for y in range(2):
        f.write(query.format(df.loc[y, "COL A"],df[y, "COL B"],df[y, "COL C"]))
```

Comment: What is the actual problem? How does your code look already? Did you google "how to iterate pandas data frame" and "how to write files in python"?

Comment: The problem now that the second iteration start from 1 not from 3. so the file consist of repetitive data

Comment: The please post your code (including a sample DataFrame in code) here, so people can help. See also [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: i've added my example code now. thanks for guiding @tturbo

Answer (score 0):

From your comment: *"The problem now that the second iteration start from 1 not from 3. so the file consist of repetitive data"*

What you want is a step=2 in your range function, so your going 0,2,4.. and inside the loop your processing the values between. See [range(start, stop, step)](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp) for help

Your code (but not tested):

```py
file_name = function_{}.sql
iterate=df[df.columns[0]].count() / 2
query = "SELECT function({0},{1},{2})"
rows_per_file = 2

for x in range(0, int(iterate), rows_per_file): # start, stop , step
    with open(file_name.format(x+1),'w') as f:
    for y in range(x, x+rows_per_file ): # start, stop
        f.write(query.format(df.loc[y, "COL A"],df[y, "COL B"],df[y, "COL C"]))
```

Comment: Btw, consider using [f-strings](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/) instead of `.format`. Its the new way to go

Comment: still doesn't get what i wanted. the problem now the  every 10000, it always exists in previous and after file .

Comment: Can you please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? (Best only with print of the indexes, withput sql and files)